# How to automate changing of settings on Android via script or app

Tags: android, automation, settings, push

Is it possible to push content such as SSID and password of a certain wi-fi network via a script, or an app that can be launched from the Android device?
I was issued to pre-configure approx. 500 tablets with certain Apps and features, one of them being setting a password for a specific SSID.
The purpose of this is that when the users of the Android tablets at the conference turn them on for the first time they would be immediately connected to the internet and have access to the content regarding the conference.
I really wish such possibility exists, so I won't have to manually configure every device.
Thank you for any constructive comments :)

Comment: Android has a support for wifi profiles backup, maybe if you create one google account with this wifi preset and the apps installed, you can obtain those simply by logging to this account on every device. Have not tried though..